# Find all files with specific mime type

Tags: 16.04, permissions, find

I copied huge number of (Android SDK) files from a shared directory to my system. Now all files which their MIME types are `application/x-shellscript` or `application/x-executable`, seems that are not executable. For example when I try to run `mksdcard` I get this error:

```
$ ./mksdcard
bash: ./mksdcard: Permission denied
```

How I can find only files with those MIME types? And then how I can change those permissions?

**Notes**:

1- When I tried `find <path> -type f -executable` with as root user it shows all files (even .PNG files) and when I tried that with standard user, it shows nothing. I do not know how to filter files with attention to their MIME type.

2- Share directory (source) currently is not accessible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `find` command doesn't test mimetype itself, but you can use it to execute the `mimetype` command and `grep` the result.

For example

```
find path/to/dir/ -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    mimetype -b "$f" | grep -Eq "application/(x-shellscript|executable)" && 
    printf "%s\n" "$f"
  done
' sh {} +
```

To perform some operation on the matching files (such as a `chmod` or `chown`), replace the `printf` command with that e.g.

```
find path/to/dir/ -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    mimetype -b "$f" | grep -Eq "application/(x-shellscript|executable)" && 
    chmod u+x "$f"
  done
' sh {} +
```

I **highly** recommend checking the current ownership and permissions **first** e.g. with `ls`

```
find path/to/dir/ -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do 
    mimetype -b "$f" | grep -Eq "application/(x-shellscript|executable)" && 
    ls -l "$f"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> man cp

Then press <kbd>/</kbd> and enter `attr` (part of 'attributes') and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Now, read the portions of the text that got marked.
Hitting <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> will make the display jump to 'n'ext or 'p'revious instance.

---

*Attempt to explain:*

Assuming that you still have the original files available you may restore the file attributes of your copied files by use of this argument to 'cp' (copy), together with your originial arguments.

```
  
       --attributes-only
              don't copy the file data, just the attributes
```

If I'm not entirely mistaken you will get the settings for all the mentioned files corrected by this.

Comment: But I do not want to copy attributes. I want to get list of those files and finally change their permissions.

Comment: Copy the attributes, your problem should be solved by that - no need to do anything else - if I'm not entirely mistaken.

Comment: I think now I understand what you say: I have to copy attributes of files from share directory to the destination. But sadly the share currently is not accessible.